# i18next deep key value react native

Tags: reactjs, native, i18next

> {
> "content": {
> "en": {
> "transfer_screen_amount_title": "Amount",
> "demo_screen_welcome_title": "Welcome"
> },
> "bm": {
> "transfer_screen_amount_title": "Jumlah",
> "demo_screen_welcome_title": "Selamat Datang"
> }
> }
> }

I reckon that in order to retrieve the value, we can set it like this **t('content.en.transfer_screen_amount_title')**.
what if i want to use it like this instead **t('transfer_screen_amount_title')** ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your translations are loaded: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations

Here an example loading the resources on init:
https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react-native/App.js#L20
So your code would look like this:

```
i18next
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    defaultNS: 'content',
    resources: {
      en: {
        content: {
          transfer_screen_amount_title: 'Amount',
          demo_screen_welcome_title: 'Welcome',
        },
      },
      bm: {
        content: {
          transfer_screen_amount_title: 'Jumlah',
          demo_screen_welcome_title: 'Selamat Datang',
        },
      },
    },
  });


// t('transfer_screen_amount_title')
```

Maybe read also: https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces

Comment: what if my json file looks like that? how do i put it in the namespace? like my json file has all these nested brackets.

Comment: Here you can find another example using a backend to load the files: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react

Comment: {
  "content": {
    "en": {
      "transfer_screen_amount_title": "Amount",
      "demo_screen_welcome_title": "Welcome"
    },
    "bm": {
      "transfer_screen_amount_title": "Jumlah",
      "demo_screen_welcome_title": "Selamat Datang"
    }
  }
}


if this is in my languagepack.json, how do i write it in i18n.js for namespace?